# How to parameterize the paraboloid $z=9-x^2-y^2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The ecuation of the paraboloid is $z=9-x^2-y^2$ I know that I can parameterize it in cartesian coordinates as $r(x,y)=(x,y,9-x^2-y^2)$ but I see in a book this parameterization of it that is $r(t)=(3cos(t),sin(t),0)$ with $0≤t≤2π$ and I don't know how to deduce it. That's my doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cillindrical coordinates i.e. use polar coordinates to describe the $xy$ plane and let $z$ depend on them.

Let $x=r\cos\theta, ~~ y= r\sin\theta, ~~ z=z$ then the parametrization for the parabolid in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ is $\Phi(r,\theta)= (r\cos \theta,~~r\sin \theta,~~9-(r\cos \theta)^2 -(r\sin \theta)^2)=(r\cos \theta,~~r\sin \theta,~~9- r^2)$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, $r \in [0,+\infty)$.